# HTML5 Strict Datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a better way to limit the values of `<input>` with `<datalist>` using only the values within the list?

**I'm looking a simple way to stricly follow the list and tag every `<input>` with `<datalist>`.**

Here's my code, yet it only point a single `<input>`. **Or how can I improve my code so that it will hit every input that has a `<datalist>`?**

```
<input list="browsers" id="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
   <option value="Internet Explorer">
   <option value="Firefox">
   <option value="Chrome">
   <option value="Opera">
   <option value="Safari">
</datalist>

<input list="cities" id="city">
<datalist id="cities">
   <option value="Baguio">
   <option value="Manila">
   <option value="Makati">
   <option value="Taguig">
   <option value="Quezon">
</datalist>

<script>
   $("#browser").on("focusout", function() {
      var opts = $('#browsers option').map(function() {
         return this.value;
      }).get();
      if(!opts.includes($("#browser").val())) {
         $.each(opts, function(index, value) {
            if(value.toUpperCase().includes($("#browser").val().toUpperCase())) {
               // suggest possible match
               $("#browser").val(value);
            }
         });
         if(!opts.includes($("#browser").val())) {
            // making it blank if entered value was not in list
            $("#browser").val("");
         }
      }
   });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82ax6hq3/
**TIA :D (y)**

Comment: Here's a plain ol' javascript version - https://jsfiddle.net/4oLjkmh0/ it shouldn't too hard to turn it into `jQuery`

Comment: That's neat. How 'bout suggesting complete value from incomplete text?

Comment: not sure about that - firefox does that natively

Comment: No, I mean your code. How will I include such code that if the entered text didn't match any value then I'll replace the text with a value that contains the text.